# Can't find DIV in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a webPage, I need to get an element by ID, but when I try to do it, the element returned is a null object.
I think because the div that I want to get is added in the HTML code when I press a button, but my JS code is compiled when the page is loaded, so JS can't find the div... How can I select my div with JS?

```
<html><head><script>
function getDiv(){
     var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
     div.innerHTML = "SOMETHING"; //div is null
     //<div id="div_name"></div> isn't added when the page is loaded
}
function addDiv()
{
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'div_name';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
}
</script></head>
<body>
<button onClick="getDiv()">GETDIV</button>
<!-- Pretend that with this button I add the div with 'div_name' in my HTML 
page -->
<button onClick="addDiv()">ADDDIV</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: do u triggering the function? for example on click?

Comment: Try putting the script i.e. the function getDIv call at the bottom of the page. Also would you consider using jQuery framework? Also, can you show part of the HTML that is relevant?

Comment: what you mean? I call the function when I click a button

Comment: I've already considered using jquery, but I think that my problem will persist

Comment: Show us how are you triggering the function.

Comment: The HTML code id hidden because another JS library show-hide my DIV

Comment: What do you mean with trigger?

Comment: load the function after loading the div;ie;soon after show/hide function

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: can you post the `addDiv()` function. Also is getdiv clicked only after adddiv? If not then that div will be undefined.

Comment: document.getElementById('div_name'); will return the div with the id="div_name" from your html.
if you want to create a div there is a different syntax for that.

Comment: yes getdiv is called after addDiv

Comment: I copied your code into an HTML file and it works !?! That is clicking adddiv then getdiv works ..

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script>

function addDiv(){
    var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
    var isDivPresent = (div && (div !== null ));

    if(isDivPresent){
     return;
    }

 var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
 createDiv.setAttribute("id", "div_name");
 createDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
 createDiv.style.width='250px';
 createDiv.style.height='300px';


 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(createDiv);
}

function getDiv(){
    var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
    var isDivPresent = (div && (div !== null ));
    
    if(!isDivPresent) { 
       addDiv();
       getDiv();
    }else {
      div.innerHTML = "SOMETHING";
    }     
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<button onClick="addDiv()">ADDDIV</button>

<button onClick="getDiv()">GETDIV</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AleConti99 :- so u first want to add a div using button click and then getDiv on button click ?

Comment: @AleConti99:- Accept my answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDiv(){
     var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
     div.innerHTML = "SOMETHING"; //div is null
}

function addDiv(){
   if(!document.getElementById('div_name')){
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     div.id = 'div_name';
     div.innerHTML = "Added Through add div";
     document.body.appendChild(div);
   }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="getDiv()">GETDIV</button>
<button onClick="addDiv()">ADDDIV</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that works as you whish. The main differences is :

I used `onclick` as attribute name instead of `onClick`

```js
function addDiv() {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.id = 'div_name';
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   div.innerHTML = 'initial content';
  }

  function updateDiv() {
   var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
   div.innerHTML = 'new content';
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

  <button onclick="addDiv();">add div</button>

  <button onclick="updateDiv();">replace div content</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click the `GETDIV` button without clicking the `ADDDIV` button first, then the *div* you're looking for isn't anywhere in the *document body*. So I would change the `getDiv()` like so:

```
function getDiv(){
     var div = document.getElementById('div_name');
     if(!div) { // if div is not added yet, then add it
       addDiv();
     }
     div.innerHTML = "SOMETHING"; //div is null
}
```